# Need assistance locating syntax error

Tags: php, syntax-error

The following code is returning a syntax error in the second elseif statement:

```
if(($Rec["gradyear"] = $mydate[year] && $mydate[month] IN ("January","February","March","April","June","July")) || ($Rec["gradyear"] = $mydate[year] -1 && $mydate[month] IN ("August","September","October","November","December"))) {
    $bgcolor="#00FF00";
} elseif(($Rec["gradyear"] = $mydate[year] -1 && $mydate[month] IN ("January","February","March","April","June","July")) || ($Rec["gradyear"] = $mydate[year] -2 && $mydate[month] IN ("August","September","October","November","December")))  {
    $bgcolor="#FFFF00";
} elseif(($Rec["gradyear"] = $mydate[year] -2 && $mydate[month] IN ("January","February","March","April","June","July")) || ($Rec["gradyear"] = $mydate[year] -3 && $mydate[month] IN ("August","September","October","November","December"))) { 
    $bgcolor="#FF0000"; $fontcolor="#FFFFFF";
}
```

For the life of me, I cannot locate it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Also, I apologize in advance if I'm not including enough information.  This is my first time posting here, so please be gentle.  :)

Comment: `$mydate[month] IN ("January","February","March","April","June","July")` doesn't look like PHP at all. Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: Seems like you need to start learning PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In** is not valid.

Use **in_array** in php.

For example:

```
in_array($mydate[month] ,
array("January","February","March","April","June","July")
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response; that fully answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "IN" with in_array for starters,change "$mydate[month]" to "$mydate['month']"...from a first glance...try to simplify your if`s...